# JOGL - translate GL_QUADS

Tags: java, opengl, jogl

In JOGL im trying to create a few 3D shapes using GL_QUADS (i.e. different components of a whole object) and so far its been fine to do this but I cant figure out how to translate the shape, there must be a way to do this but im not very familiar with GL_QUADS so im not entirely sure how to go about this. Editing `gl.glVertex3f` just results in the shape being a different size which seems to be the only thing I can edit, is it possible to give a GL_QUAD a variable name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `glTranslatef` function:

```
// render the shape
gl.glTranslatef(5.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f); // translate along x, y, z
// render the shape - you will now have two shapes next to each other
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried this before asking but it never did anything? Is it because I have `public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {` with quite a few `glBegin` in?

Comment: The command has no effect if you put it inside `glBegin`...`glEnd`. It has to be called before `glBegin`. Only a few JOGL/OpenGL commands are valid within `glBegin`...`glEnd`: http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter02.html If this doesn't help, it would be the best if you could post your source code.

Comment: Worked perfectly after putting it before `glBegin` thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Calling `gl.glTranslatef(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);` will apply to the current matrix in the stack, effectively meaning that whatever you draw from then on will appear 1 unit along on the x axis from whatever the matrix was on before (probably the origin in your case).

I can see why it might seem confusing, rather than creating the shape *then* moving it (can't be done, it's already been drawn), you'll want to translate *then* draw your shape.

For example:

```
gl.glPushMatrix();
    gl.glTranslatef(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
        // draw some vertices here
    gl.glEnd();
gl.glPopMatrix();
```